# Differentiating space curves

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis, functional-style

I'm trying to do some very basic differential geometry of space curves. For example, a space curve $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ has unit tangent and normal vectors given by
$$t(s)=\frac{\gamma'(s)}{\lVert\gamma'(s)\rVert},\\
n(s)=\frac{t'(s)}{\lVert t'(s)\rVert}.$$
I want to define functions that would compute the tangent and normal vectors of an arbitrary curve at any $s$. I tried it in a higher-order functional style, like in say Haskell:

```
norm[x_] := Sqrt[x.x]
tangent[γ_] := Function[s, γ'[s]/norm[γ'[s]]]
normal[γ_] := Function[s, tangent[γ]'[s]/norm[tangent[γ]'[s]]]
```

(I need to define my own `norm` because Mathematica doesn't like to differentiate `Norm`.)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Let `γ[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s], 0}` be our test curve, a circle. Then `normal[γ][1] // N` does not return a vector, but instead a bizarre expression involving the dot product of `1.` and a vector. I have no idea how to begin figuring out what's going on.

I can do it in a less elegant way as

```
tangent[γ_, s_] := γ'[s]/norm[γ'[s]]
normal[γ_, s_] := D[tangent[γ, ss], ss]/norm[D[tangent[γ, ss], ss]] /. ss -> s
```

but this requires the use of a dummy variable and the not-so-pretty `D[tangent[γ, ss], ss]` construction.

Why does my original implementation not work, and is there a simple way to fix it?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612 ?  If you put for `r[t]` a different curve it should work as well.

Comment: @Artes: I hadn't seen that before. But I'd rather not redefine `tangent` and `normal` for every curve I might be interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `normal` isn't working because the derivative is getting "confused" because of the way that your functions pass parameters:

```
multiplyBy2[r_] := Function[s, 2 r[s]]
r[s_] := {s^2, s^2}
r'[s]
multiplyBy2'[r][s]
```

As demonstrated by evaluating the above, the apostrophe sees that your parameter is `r`, so it takes the derivative with respect to `r`. That's how the `1` appears in your expression. Specifically, in your original functions, this `1` (derivative of the vector with respect to itself) appears where we expect a vector still, thus creating the unwanted dot products.

This can be avoided by being more explicit with what we want to derive (note simply taking the derivative with respect to `s` inside the function won't work as `s` will be replaced by its value before the derivative is taken, resulting in an error).

Thus, in my approach, I use a "dummy" variable, true, but I think the code still remains fairly concise and avoids `ReplaceAll`.

```
norm[x_] := Sqrt[x.x]
tangent[γ_] := Function[s, γ'[s]/norm[γ'[s]]]
normal[γ_] := 
  With[{deriv = Function[x, Evaluate[D[tangent[γ][x], x]]]}, 
    Function[s, deriv[s]/norm[deriv[s]]]
  ]
γ[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s], 0}
normal[γ][1] // N
```

Finally, when actually using these function, such as within a manipulate, I strongly recommend that you create an evaluated version of the tangent and normal functions for the specific function that is being looked at, thus avoiding constant and expensive re-derivation. I.e., doing something like this:

```
solenoid[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s], s}
solTan = tangent[solenoid];
solNorm = normal[solenoid];
```

**EDIT**

It has come to my attention that something closer to what OP's code uses is `multiplyBy2[r]'[s]`. After reviewing the `Trace` of this expression, it is clear as to why the expression evaluates to a matrix - the `'` automatically takes the derivative of the sub-expression in `Function`:

```
Function[a, x]' hi
(* hi Function[a, 0] *)
```

It appears that, completely independent of the parameters of the function, the `'` travels to `x`, yielding `Function[a, x'] hi` (again, see the `Trace`). Since `x` is a symbol with no parameters, `x'` evaluates to 0.

However, in my example, something even more confusing happens: In the `Trace`, the following steps occur `Function[s$,2 r[s$]]',Function[s$,{2 r'[s$],2 r'[s$]}]`, from which we can see how a matrix may result. Why this happens, I don't know. This is why we explicitly define what we are deriving with respect to.

Comment: A closer analogue would be `multiplyBy2[r]'[s]`, but that strangely yields a matrix, which is still not what I expected. I guess I see the problem, though I'm still in the dark about why it happens. Should I just avoid using primes on higher-order functions?

Comment: @RahulNarain I took a look at the `Trace` of the expression in your comment, and, as I have singled out in my answer, for some reason, Mathematica jumps from my specified expression to something completely unexplainable. Yes, I would suggest only using primes on symbols that are defined on a "single level."

Answer (score 1):

As VF1's answer explains, the problem is indeed that the prime behaves strangely in `tangent[γ]'`. I replaced it with a function

```
d[f_] := Function[x, Evaluate[D[f[x], x]]]
```

based on the construction in VF1's answer, and now everything works as expected.

```
tangent[γ_] := Function[s, d[γ][s]/norm[d[γ][s]]]
normal[γ_] := Function[s, d[tangent[γ]][s]/norm[d[tangent[γ]][s]]]

γ1[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s], s} (* a helix! *)
γ2[s_] := {s, s^2, 0}
{normal[γ1][s], normal[γ2][s]} // Simplify[#, Assumptions :> s ∈ Reals] &
(* {{-Cos[s], -Sin[s], 0}, {-((2 s)/Sqrt[1 + 4 s^2]), 1/Sqrt[1 + 4 s^2], 0}} *)
```

Comment: Probably I should also replace every `Function[s, ...]` with `Function[s, Evaluate[...]]` for performance as VF1 suggested. Or would that have any side effects?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple fix of the OP's definitions:

```
norm[x_] := Sqrt[x.x]
tangent[γ_] := Function[s, Evaluate[γ'[s]/norm[γ'[s]]]]
normal[γ_] := Function[s, Evaluate[tangent[γ]'[s]/norm[tangent[γ]'[s]]]]
```

The evaluation of the bodies will take care of the difficulties of `tangent[γ]'[s]`.  (The evaluation of the body of `normal` is not necessary, unless you plan to take its derivative.) One gets for example

```
γ[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s], 0};
normal[γ][1] // N
(* -> {-0.540302, -0.841471, 0.} *)
```

The reason for the trouble in the original definition of `tangent` is that the (symbolic) derivative of `γ'[s]/norm[γ'[s]]` is

```
γ᾽᾽[s]/norm[γ'[s]] - norm'[γ'[s]] γ᾽[s] γ''[x]/norm[γ᾽[s]]^2
```

You might note that `γ[s]` is not treated as a vector.  More precisely, when the chain rule is applied to the derivative of `norm[γ'[s]]`, `γ'[s]` is treated as a scalar.

*N.B.*  There is a difference between `Norm` and the OP's `norm`.  `Norm` assumes its arguments might be `Complex`, and uses `Abs`, which can complicate derivatives.  For instance, with `Norm` in place of `norm`, `normal[γ][1] // N` has things like `Derivative[1][Abs][0.540302]` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define one function only, keep the built-in `Norm` and use pure functions:

```
derVec[\[Gamma]_] := 
Module[{local}, local = Derivative[1][\[Gamma]];
 Function[x, Evaluate[Simplify[local[x]/Norm[local[x]], Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals}
                      ]
             ]
 ]
]
```

Example :

```
curve = Function[s, {Cos[s], Sin[s], s}];

{tangent, normal} = Rest@NestList[derVec, curve, 2]
```

Comment: This computes $\gamma''(s)/\lVert\gamma''(s)\rVert$, which is not the same as the normal. One can see this, for example, on the parabola $(s,s^2,0)$.

Comment: @RahulNarain True, should have thought about it, thanks. Will correct.

Comment: @RahulNarain Done.