# Drawing normals to a curve

Tags: plotting

I want to draw a series of normals to a curve, where the curve has been 
parametrized by a single angle, i.e., the polar angle. The curve is actually 
sinusoidal perturbation of a circle of radius 1/2, and the magnitude of the perturbation is given by `amp`.

I have the `normal` function calculated in the code below already. I want to be able to draw normals to the curve at different points on  the curve. How do I do this?

```
orad       = 1/2;
amp        = 0.05;
numpetals  = 7; 

(*Polar information of interface*)
r[th_]  := orad + amp * Sin[numpetals*th];
rp[th_] := amp*numpetals*Cos[numpetals*th];

(*Cartesian information of interface*)
x[th_]  := r[th]*Cos[th]; (*X-coordinate of the interface/*)
y[th_]  := r[th]*Sin[th]; (*Y-coordinate of the interface*)

(*Speeds of traveral*)
xp[th_] := rp[th]*Cos[th] - r[th]*Sin[th];
yp[th_] := rp[th]*Sin[th] + r[th]*Cos[th];

(*Outward unit normal to the curve*)
normal[th_] := {yp[th], -xp[th]}/Sqrt[xp[th]^2 + yp[th]^2];
```

Comment: look at this [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18598/5478) Q&A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using `PolarPlot`.

```
normalArrows = Table[Arrow[{{x[th], y[th]}, {x[th], y[th]} + 0.1 normal[th]}], {th,
 0, 360 \[Degree], 4 \[Degree]}];
PolarPlot[r[th], {th, 0, 360 \[Degree]}, Epilog -> normalArrows, PlotRange -> 0.65]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `normalArrows = Table[Arrow[TranslationTransform[{x[θ], y[θ]}] /@ {{0, 0}, - 0.1 Cross[Normalize[{x'[θ], y'[θ]}]]}], {θ, 0, 360 °, 4 °}]`.

Comment: Cool. With descriptive function names this makes things very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

If I redefine `normal`, it is easy to plot the curve and its normals.

```
orad = 1/2;
amp = 0.05;
numpetals = 7;

r[th_] := orad + amp*Sin[numpetals*th]
rp[th_] := amp*numpetals*Cos[numpetals*th]

x[th_] := r[th]*Cos[th]; 
y[th_] := r[th]*Sin[th];

xp[th_] := rp[th]*Cos[th] - r[th]*Sin[th]
yp[th_] := rp[th]*Sin[th] + r[th]*Cos[th]

normal[th_] := Module[{unit, nx, ny},
  unit = Normalize@{xp[th], yp[th]};
  nx = unit[[2]]; ny = -unit[[1]];
  {{x[t], y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]} + {nx, ny}}]

Framed @ ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, 0., 360 °},
  Epilog -> Table[Line[normal[t]], {t, 0., 360 °, 45 °}], 
  PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image: plot.png]

Answer (score 2):

Same approach (ParametricPlot, Epilog) as m_goldberg but with your definition for the normal.

```
points = Table[th, {th, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}]
ParametricPlot[
 {x[th], y[th]},
 {th, -Pi, Pi},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[Medium],
   Point[{x[#], y[#]} & /@ points],
   Arrow[{
       {x[#], y[#]},
       {x[#], y[#]} + 0.2 normal[#]
       }] & /@ points
   }, PlotRange -> .7
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Say you have this data points.

```
points = Table[{x[th], y[th]}, {th, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}];
```

And this is your line.

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[points];
```

And the normals will be simply lines joining these pair of points (as per your code).

```
norm = Table[{{x[th], y[th]}, normal[th]}, {th, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}];
(*I choose here 1/10th of total points or it will be too clumsy *)
```

Then you can plot them if you wish

```
p2 = Graphics[{Table[Line[norm[[i]]], {i, Length[norm]}],
Point[Table[norm[[i]][[1]], {i, Length[norm]}]]}, Axes -> True];
```

And then you combine the both.

```
Show[{p2, p1}]
```

This will look something like

```
Grid[{{"Plot", "Normal", "Combine"}, {p1, p2, Show[{p2, p1}]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: norm]

Please don't mind the aspect ratios. You can always fix them.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, but the indicated line segments don't look like normals to me, under the figure named `combine`, Is there some bug in your code?

Comment: Thanks @smilingbuddha for the comment. It is because your code calculate normal at a point and it is made for a particular trajectory. When I choose only few points, the trajectory is not very clear and hence the normal doesn't appear to be 'normal'. It will be prominent when you take large number of points (what I have done now) and the normality will be more soothing to eye.