# Draw Vector Tangent to Point on Parameterized Curve

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

I define the vector function $\vec{r}(t)$ by

```
r[t_] = {t, Cos[t], Sin[t]}
```

The command `r'[t]` gives the vector tangent to the curve drawn by $r(t)$ for any specified value of $t$.

I can generate the curve for $r(t)$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ via

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

What I would like to do is draw a tangent vector whose tail actually touches the curve. For example, I would like to draw the vector described by $r^\prime(0)$ with its tail at $r(0)$. Even better would be to wrap this inside `Manipulate` and draw the tangent vector for any $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. How can I accomplish either of these goals?

Comment: This is closely related or a duplicate of [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt). For the actual answer look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)

Comment: Typing "vector tangent" to the search engine shows many references which may help you. You should have done this first to avoid waste of your time spent on proper formatting (+1) :).

Comment: They say duplicates shouldn't be deleted (look e.g. here [What are the guidelines for voting to delete questions?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/what-are-the-guidelines-for-voting-to-delete-questions)). You could provide an answer to your question, so that should be helpful anyway.