# Finding the tangent to a piecewise function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I'm new to Mathematica and I am trying to calculate the expression of the tangent to the curve

```
f[X_] = 
  Piecewise[{{-X^2 + 4 X - 3, X < 3}, {3 - X (Abs[X - 4]), X >= 3}}]
```

at `x = 2`.

I have to draw the function and the tangent line. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: See the [plotting documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html) and the [piecewise documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Comment: See some of the "Related" links on the right, such as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31251/draw-vector-tangent-to-point-on-parameterized-curve, etc.

Comment: You also might find help following this link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, easy. Just calulate the slope at $x=2$ and then, plot the tangent with that slope and through the point $(2, f(2))$.

The slope is calulated as the first derivative of $f(x)$ in $x=2$:

```
D[f[v], v] /. v -> 2
```

and the tangent line passing through $(2, f(2))$ with $f(2)=1$ is:

```
X*(D[f[v], v] /. v -> 2) + f[2]
```

Plotting both functions:

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{-3 + 4 X - X^2, X < 3}, {3 - X Abs[-4 + X], X >= 3}}, 0],
X*(D[f[v], v] /. v -> 2) + f[2]}, {X, 0, 5}, 
PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{2, f[2]}]}]
```

[image]