# Using Manipulate, how do you display the points on the curve and the tangent vector?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, vector

I'm new to Mathematica and my assignment is very vague... I'm hoping someone can explain to me a bit more of that this quesion means:

> Given the curve C, display the point on the curve and the tangent
>   vector there for t=[0,1]. Use the manipulate function.

I do not want the answer, just an expansion on this question if someone else understands what I am supposed to do. Pointing me in the correct direction would be great. I don't even know what function to use, which means I do not even know enough to Google this problem...

Comment: Make a line that goes through that point and another point which is on the curve and very close to that point. Also, is the curve a given function?

Comment: If you do not want the answer, but the explanation then the question suits mathematics SE, because it is not really related ot *Mathematica* ...

Comment: @Arcostick, The curve function was given. I didn't post it due to my schools copy write restrictions. I can make up another one if necessary.

Comment: @Sektor, I posted the question here because I would like to know which Mathematica functions I should look in to. I kind of understand the concept, but have no idea how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: @Artes, I saw that post, but it wasn't closely related enough for me to get any useful information out of.

Comment: Have you read this [one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)???