# Animating arrows

Tags: animation

I have the following Code:

```
No={{1, 2}, {1}};
arrows={{{{0, 0}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {1, 1}}}, {{{0, 0}, {1,
 3}}}};
colors={Blue,Blue,Blue};
Animate[Graphics[{Sequence @@ {colors[[#]], 
   Arrow @@ (arrows[[t]][[#]])} & /@ No[[t]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}], {t, Range[1, 2]}]
```

This does not seem work. It should display 3 arrows at time step 1 and only 1 at t=2... Do you have an idea?

Comment: Shouldn't it display 1 arrow at step 2?

Comment: Yes t=1 => 3 arrows and t=2 => 1 Arrow

Comment: Is [that](http://i.imgur.com/l7WLuPE.gif) what you are after?

Comment: Yes indeed. Does it not work in the above way?

Comment: It doesn't work, but `Sequence@@` and `Arrow@@` is not the easiest way IMO

Comment: Take a look at this answer for a reference how you could  animate  arrows: [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you should use `Thread` in your case:

```
arrows = {{{{0, 0}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {1, 1}}}, 
          {{{0, 0}, {1, 3}}}};
colors = Array[#, #2] & @@@ Thread[{{Blue &, Red &}, Length /@ arrows}]
Animate[Graphics[Thread@{colors[[t]], Arrow /@ arrows[[t]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 4}}], {t, {1, 2}}]
```

[image]