# Abort during animation

Tags: export, animation

I am running an animation with the following command:

```
files = FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "*.dat"]; 
MTnumbers = FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "MTnumbers.txt"];

data = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files
MT = Import[#, "List"] & /@ MTnumbers


coords = {{#1 - (#3/2), #2 - (height/2)}, {#1 + (#3/2), #2 + (height/
       2)}} & @@@ #[[All, 2 ;;]] & /@ data;

height = 2;

colors = {Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, 
Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, 
Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, 
Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue};
Animate[Graphics[{Sequence @@ {colors[[#]], 
   Rectangle @@ (coords[[#]][[t]])} & /@ MT[[1]]},
PlotRange -> {{-1000, 1000}, {-200, 200}}, 
ImageSize -> {1000, 200}], {t, Range[0, 7000]}] 

Export["tubuli.avi", %];
```

As soon as I try to export this output Mathematica crashes. 
When I increase the number of rectangles to about 150 the simulation crashes without giving an output. Is my computer too weak or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

The data is in the following zip archive you just need the notebook and the data in the same folder and it should work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iegdb1a031i4mn6/data.zip

Comment: IMO you should just provide the lists of `coords` and `MT`. You can put them [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so _Mathematica_ can `Import` them. If not, you can paste them here and I will put them on _pastebin_.

Comment: I edited the post. Gif export also crashes or returns a non moving gif. Do you know if it is possible add the command from this Answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48971/animating-arrows into the animation or can't I combine sequence and thread in one graphic?

Comment: yeah I thought so... But basically my data is equal to what is written in the file and the animation works but the export aborts.

Comment: what i mean is: When I type data the output looks like the one in the file. Should I provide another format?

Comment: @user3683367 You should test the code you post here ...:)

Comment: Yes but I do not know how to import data from the web. Of course it does not work like this on my computer. How would you include the files?

Comment: Im sorry I still do not understand. The files in the dropbox link are already in the {{}{}{}- form wanted by mathematica. What do you mean by directly? I cannot put them on paste bin because they're too big.

Comment: No I can only send this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv6rkcd5cl6va8q/data.txt which leads to a download...

Comment: I can provide a zipped file with all relevant data?

Comment: so I linked an zip archive with all the data one only needs to put the contents in the same folder as the notebook containing the code. After executing the Export  mathematica still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what is your issue here and your goal but tell me if that fits you:

```
datfiles=ToString@StringForm["MT_mathematica_``.dat",#]&/@Range@40;
MT=Range@40;
data=ToExpression@Import["Your/Path/Here"<>#]&/@datfiles;
height=2;
rect=Rectangle[Sequence@@#]&;
coords={{#1-(#3/2),#2-(height/2)},{#1+(#3/2),#2+(height/2)}}&@@@#[[All,2;;]]&/@data;
frames=Table[Graphics[{Blue,rect@coords[[1,t]]},PlotRange->{{-100,100},{-200,200}},Frame->True],{t,1,Length@First@coords,100}];
Export["~/MT.gif",frames,"DisplayDurations"->.1]
```

[image]

I reduced the number of frames and the `ImageSize/PlotRange` to see something.

Comment: Ok it worked like this for one rectangle. I will try to export all rectangles in 1 file now to see if it works.

Comment: If it doesn't work it won't be because of _Mathematica_ but because of your computer I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok thats fine I just needed to know if it it works before I put it on some better computer. So basically I can switch Blue => colors[[#]] and add & /@ MT[[1]] behind the"}" bracket and a gif involving all rectangles will be made?

Comment: Just make sure that `colors` has the correct `Length`. But basically `{colors[[#]],rect@coords[[#,t]]}& /@ MT[[1]]` should do it.