# How to find the magnitude of a vector?

Tags: vector, differential-geometry

I'm doing this exercise in [Wagner's book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat/22724#22724) (p.78)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

, and this is my attempt:

```
Clear[curvature];

(*Define curvature function *)
curvature[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{s, v, T},
  s = {x, y, z};
  v = D[s, t];
  T = v/Norm[v];
  Simplify[Norm[D[T, t]/Norm[v]]]]

(* Apply function to Cos[t],Sin[t],t *)
curvature[Cos[t], Sin[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you could see I did not get the expected answer (1/2) when applying my curvature function.

It also would not reduce even when a value for t was substituted:

```
curvature[Cos[t], Sin[t], t] /. t -> 4
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, following Wagner's solution where he defines a separate magnitude function does work:

```
Clear[curvature];

(* Define function to find magnitude of a vector *)
mag[vec_] := Sqrt[vec.vec]

(* Define curvature function *)
curvature[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{s, v, T},
  s = {x, y, z};
  v = D[s, t];
  T = v/mag[v];
  Simplify[mag[D[T, t]/mag[v]]]]

(* Apply function to Cos[t],Sin[t],t *)
curvature[Cos[t], Sin[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems pretty clear that using Norm to find the magnitude of a vector does not work in this case. More specifically, using Norm doesn't seem to simplify trigonometric results unless the t is substituted

```
Norm[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]
Norm[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}] /. t -> 4 // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm very fuzzy on my matrix knowledge so I'd really appreciate an explanation on why Norm doesn't seem to return the expected answer in this case. Also, is there any other way to find a vector's magnitude that will give the correct answer without defining a new function?

Comment: `Simplify[Norm[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}], Element[t, Reals]]`...

Comment: This is a related post: [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt), and explicitly [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/56469#56469) is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Norm in general assumes complex arguments and uses `Abs` to provide for that:

```
Norm[{x, y}]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[y]^2]

For real elements, you can either add an assumption for `Simplify` or manually get rid of `Abs` beforehand:

```
Simplify[Norm[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}], Element[t, Reals]]
Simplify[Norm[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}] /. Abs -> Identity]
```

> 1
>
> 1

This now returns the desired result for real `t`:

```
curvature[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{s, v, T}, s = {x, y, z};
  v = D[s, t];
  T = v/Norm[v];
  Simplify[Norm[D[T, t]/Norm[v]] /. Abs -> Identity]]

curvature[Cos[t], Sin[t], t]
```

> 1/2

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

With **V10** we can use

```
ArcCurvature[2 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, t]
```

> 1/2

Or

```
FrenetSerretSystem[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, t]
```

[image]

yielding curvature, tangent, and normal

**Original answer**

An alternative:

```
$Assumptions = t \[Element] Reals;

J[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x}

Curvature[a_][t_] := a''[t].J[a'[t]]/Norm[J[a'[t]]]^3 // Simplify

circle[a_][t_] := {a Cos[t], a Sin[t]}

Curvature[circle[2]][t]
```

[image]

```
ellipse[a_, b_][t_] := {a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}

Curvature[ellipse[2, 3]][t]
```

[image]

```
Curvature[ellipse[2, 3]][Pi]
```

[image]

```
$Assumptions = True; (* Clear *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you help me understand why you defined a function with 2 parameters in separate brackets?

Comment: @seismatica I think it's just a matter of personal taste. Makes code clearer for me in the ellipse-case (`t` vs. `Pi`).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version of `curvature` that uses *Mathematica* machinery not available to Wagner, who used V3.

```
curvature[x_, y_, z_] :=
  Module[{s, v, vMag, T},
    Block[{$Assumptions = {{x, y, z} ∈ Reals}},
      s = {x, y, z};
      v = D[s, t];
      vMag = Surd[v.v, 2];
      T = v/vMag;
      Simplify[Norm[D[T, t]/vMag]]]]
curvature[Cos[t], Sin[t], t]
```

> ```
> 1/2
> ```

Comment: That post would have been also great from @Sjoerd: Surd by Sjoerd :D

Comment: @YvesKlett. Perhaps Sjoerd thought that using `Surd` to eliminate `Abs` was absurd :D

Comment: hehe, I had that one coming :-)