# Simple Plot of Vector

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a vector $<x(t),y(t),z(t)>$ constrained to a unit sphere.  I am trying to plot what the vector looks like as time progresses.  What would be the easiest approach to visualizing this?

I have

```
x[t_, α_] := -1/Sqrt[1 + α^2]  Sin[ t Sqrt[1 + α^2]]
y[t_, α_] := -α/(1 + α^2) (Cos[t Sqrt[1 + α^2]] - 1)
z[t_, α_] := -1 - (1 - Cos[t Sqrt[1 + α^2]])/(1 + α^2)
```

I want to plot the vector as a function of t [0,10] and I guess alpha=1.

Comment: Can you post example data?

Comment: Edited above with my functions

Comment: @yankeefan11 You should use `=` rather than `:=` when possible. In this case nothing needs to be delayed (`:=` is named "SetDelayed").

Comment: Related: [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Show[Graphics3D[{
    {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 0, 0}}]},
    {Opacity[0.2], 
     Sphere[{0, a/(1 + a^2), -1 - 1/(1 + a^2)}, 1/Sqrt[1 + a^2]]}, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {x[t, a], y[t, a], z[t, a]}}]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, a], y[u, a], z[u, a]}, {u, 0, 10}], 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> Table[{-3, 2}, {3}]], {t, 0, 10}, {a, 1, 
  4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you generate that gif using just mathematica?

Comment: @Coolwater LICECap software to screen capture

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ParametricPlot3D` for this kind of plot. Use `Graphics3D` if you want to visualize the sphere too.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x[t, 1], y[t, 1], z[t, 1]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.31],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0.0, 0.5, -1.5}, 1/Sqrt[2]]}]
 ]
```

[image]