# TNB vectors placed on a piecewise parametric curve

Tags: graphics3d, parametric-functions, vector-calculus

```
r[t_] = Piecewise[{{{7 t, 0, 4 (1 + Cos[ t])}, 
     0 <= t <= π}, {{5 Cos[t - 3 π/2] + 7*π, 
      3 Sin[t - 3 π/2] + 3, 0}, π < t <= 
      2 π}, {{7*π + 3*Cos[t - 3 π/2], 
      2*3 - 3 + 3*Sin[t - 3 π/2], 2/(3 π) (t - 2 π)^2}, 
     2 π < t <= 4 π}, {{7 π - 5 (t - 4 π), 
      6 + 4 ((t - 4 π)/π)^3, 
      2 - 1/π t^2 + 10 t - 22 π}, 
     4 π < t <= 5 π}, {{-3 t + 17 π, 10, 
      2 - 972 π + 540 t - (99 t^2)/π + (6 t^3)/π^2}, 
     5 π < t <= 6 π}, {{-π - 3 Sin[t], 
      9/40 (1/3 (20 + 18 π) - t)^2, 3 Cos[t] - 1}, 
     6 π < t <= 
      8 π}, {{-25 π + 25 t - (19 t^2)/(4 π) + t^3/(
       4 π^2), -(25/2) (140 - 132 π + 27 π^2) + (
       15 (80 - 74 π + 15 π^2) t)/(2 π) - (
       3 (180 - 164 π + 33 π^2) t^2)/(
       8 π^2) - ((-50 + 45 π - 9 π^2) t^3)/(20 π^3), 
      1058 - (360 t)/π + (81 t^2)/(2 π^2) - (3 t^3)/(
       2 π^3)}, 8 π < t <= 10 π}}];
```

I have no idea how to put the vectors on the curve, im not sure even if i calculated the right vectors. I found a similar question on this site and used the method I found there, but now im stuck on plotting the vectors. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I used to get the three vectors as well.

```
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t ∈ Reals]
vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t ∈ Reals]
vB[t_] := Simplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]], t ∈ Reals]
```

I want to place such vectors at `t = 7π/2` and `t = 13π/2`

Comment: But you've read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598) already, right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I posted an answer as the OP uses the functions (copy and pasted) from the links suggested by you and Jens...this piecewise function, I think posed some challenges so I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the comment is excellent. To plot TNB frame to a point you need to a line/arrow from point ($\vec{r}(t)$ to relevant vector, e.g. $\vec{r}(t)+\vec{T}(t)$.

There are some indeterminate points (at piecewise junctions but the desired points are well defined). Just for illustration:

```
tang[t_] := r'[t]/Sqrt[r'[t].r'[t]]
norm[t_] := tang'[t]/Sqrt[tang'[t].tang'[t]]
bin[t_] := Cross[tang[t], norm[t]]
arr[t_] := Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + 4 #}] & /@ Through[{tang, norm, bin}[t]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 10 Pi}], 
  Graphics3D[{Riffle[{Red, Green, Blue}, arr[angle
      ]], {Purple, If[p1 == 1, arr[7 Pi/4], Sequence[]], Pink, Thick, 
     If[p2 == 1, arr[13 Pi/4], Sequence[]]}}]], {angle, 0.01, 
  10 Pi - 0.01}, {{p1, 0, 7 Pi/4}, {0, 1}, 
  Checkbox}, {{p2, 0, 13 Pi/4}, {0, 1}, Checkbox}]
```

[image]

Notes:
(i) the reason I redefined the tangent, norm and binormal was due to problems with `Norm`...
(ii) the `FrenetSerretSystem` had problems with this piecewise function but I have used for simpler functions