# Finding unit tangent for a given r(t)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus, homework

For my Calc III class, I need to find $T(t)$, $N(t)$, and $k(t)$ using *Mathematica*, given $r(t) = {sqrt(t), (1/2)t^2, t^3 - (5/2)t^2 - 17}$. While the former and latter have been found, attempting to use the same method used to get $T(t)$ in order to find $N(t)$ has had... *messy* results, as seen in the following image.

[image]
(If the image doesn't show, it is basically an eight line mess full of `Abs`.

The code used is:

```
N1[t_] = Simplify[T'[t] / Norm[T'[t]], t ∈ Reals]
```

By hand, it starts getting ridiculously nasty around $||T'(t)||$, and I can't even begin to figure out $N(t)$, so I couldn't tell you if the result given is even remotely correct. What *Mathematica* gave me for $T(t)$ matched up with what I got by hand, so I know that, at the very least, *Mathematica* got that right or otherwise as wrong as I have.

I've tried doing a Google search for anything that could help compute $N(t)$, but nothing has proven useful.

For $T(t)$, I have gotten the following:
[image]

```
T(t) = {1 / sqrt(t) sqrt((1/t)(4t^3((3t - 5)^2 + 1) + 1)), 2t / sqrt((1/t)(4t^3((3t - 5)^2 + 1) + 1)), 2t(3t - 5) / sqrt((1/t)(4t^3((3t - 5)^2 + 1) + 1))}
```

(I apologize if the formatting is nasty; I've never really done this before, so I don't know how to properly clean it up.)

Comment: Probably better off avoiding `Norm[]` altogether: `Simplify[T'[t]/Sqrt[T'[t].T'[t]]]`. You might be interested in looking at `FrenetSerretSystem[]`, too.

Comment: It helped... some. Insofar as it reduced it to a two-line mess of fractions full of `Abs`.

Comment: I mean, you should use something similar to get your tangent vector, too: `Simplify[r'[t]/Sqrt[r'[t].r'[t]]]`. Make sure to clear all variables before trying all of these.

Comment: ... Wow. Oh wow, that's beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it only closely related [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt) or simply a duplicate?  If not try to explain why?

Comment: @Artes This is not a duplicate of the linked question. I tried the solution presented, and the results were confusing; I needed a different way of going about it. The difference in the equations is probably the reason why Mathematica had been giving me difficulties with your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace the assumption for `Simplify` with

```
t > 0
```

and it will work. The reason is that your function contains a square root of `t` which precludes evaluation of the Euclidean norm for $t<0$.