# Passing a function into another function defined with Module and using it there

Tags: graphics, functions, vector-calculus

I'm trying to write a generic module that will take a vector-valued function of a space curve and show the animation of a unit tangent vector traversing the curve. I found a really nice example from [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18612/3066) in an answer to another question. His answer isn't generic, so I tried to generalize it in the form of a module:

```
UnitTangentParametricPlot3D[vfunction_, intvl_] := 
  Module[{p, v, vu},
    p[t_] := vfunction;
    v[h_] := D[p[t],t];
    vu[g_] := Simplify[v[h]/Norm[v[h]]];
 Animate[
   Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[{p[t]}, intvl, Mesh -> Full],
     Graphics3D[ 
       Thick, Darker @ Red, Arrow[{p[s], p[s] + vu[s]}]],
       PlotRange -> Full,
       ViewPoint -> {4, 8, 0},
       ImageSize -> 600],
   {s, -1, 1}]]
```

I'm having trouble working with generic functions in the following ways:

- Take a function as module argument a, find its derivative and evaluate it through the animated value s.
- Animate an arrow graphics object

Sorry for missing anything obvious, I'm new to Mathematica.

**Updated working code thanks to Henrick's suggestions :**

```
    SetAttributes[UnitAnimateParametricPlot3D, HoldAll];
UnitAnimateParametricPlot3D[vfunction_, {x_, a_, b_}, scale_, size_] := Module[{p, v, uT},
    Block[{t,k},
        p[t_] := Evaluate[vfunction /. {x -> t}];
        v[k_] := D[p[t],t]/.{x -> k};
        uT[t_]:= Simplify[v[t]/Norm[v[t]]];
    ];
    Animate[
        Show[
            ParametricPlot3D[ {p[t]}, {x, a, b}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio-> 1, Mesh -> Full, ImageSize->size],
            Graphics3D[
                {Thick, Darker @ Red, Arrow[{p[s], (p[s] + scale*uT[s])}]}],
                ViewPoint -> Front,
                PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
                ImageSize -> size],
    {s,a,b}, AnimationRunning->True, AnimationDirection->ForwardBackward, AnimationRepetitions->3]
]
```

The new scale_ parameter allows for the user to scale the arrow so they can see it traverse the curve.

The new plot-range now only takes the plot-range of the curve, instead of include the animated vector's range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SetAttributes[UnitTangentParametricPlot3D, HoldAll];
UnitTangentParametricPlot3D[vfunction_, {x_, a_, b_}] := 
 Module[{p, v, vu, background,plora},
  Block[{t},
   p[t_] := Evaluate[vfunction /. {x -> t}];
   v[t_] := Evaluate[D[p[t], t]];
   vu[t_] := Evaluate[Simplify[Normalize[v[t]]]];
   ];
  background = ParametricPlot3D[{p[t]}, {t, a, b}];
  plora = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[background]) + {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}};
  Manipulate[
   Show[{
     background,
     Graphics3D[{Thick, Darker@Red, Arrow[{p[s], p[s] + vu[s]}]}]
     },
    PlotRange -> plora,
    ViewPoint -> {4, 8, 0},
    ImageSize -> 600
    ],
   {s, a, b}
   ]
  ]
```

For the future remember that `Graphics` with multiple objects and directives requires a pair of braces `{}`. Moreover, the arguments in the definitions for `p`, `v` and `vu` did not match the symbol of the argument on the right hand side. In fact, this symbol has to be extracted from the arguments of `UnitTangentParametricPlot3D`.

The reason to give `UnitTangentParametricPlot3D` the attribute `HoldAll` was to make the following work:

```
t = 4;
UnitTangentParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.1 t}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

The problem is that the symbol `t` has already a value assigned when we call `UnitTangentParametricPlot3D`; `HoldAll` prevents evaluation. Afterwards, we use `vfunction /. {x -> t}` in the body of `UnitTangentParametricPlot3D` in order have a controlable variable name.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I realize now that I didn't read the parameters specifications for Arrow or Graphics3D carefully; thanks for pointing that out. Also, I think I better understand handling variables in modules.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to make it so the plot range in Show[] is unaffected by my vector graphics3D? I've been looking through the PlotRange[] api for a while now. Actually, I just got it! (See updates).

Comment: Have a look at the last edit. I extracted the `PlotRange` of `background` and widened it by `1`.