# How to make a vector field point by point?

Tags: plotting, vector

I have data for the components of the vectors at multiple points and want to plot something like a vector field from my points which obviously has to be done vector by vector because I do not know the equation of the field that I plot.

Is there a way I can plot the vectors vector by vector in 3D space?

Comment: Have you seen `ListVectorPlot[]` and `ListVectorPlot3D[]`?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica has a graphics primitive, `Arrow`, that will do what you ask. You may also need the graphics primitive `Arrowheads` to adjust the look of the arrowheads if you don't like the default arrowheads.

To demonstrate the use of `Arrow`, I will generate a set of tangents to function given by

```
f[x_] := 4 - x^2

vector[tail : {_, _}, slope_, length_: 1.] :=
  Module[{θ = ArcTan[slope]}, {tail, tail + length {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}}]

tangetVectors = N @ Table[vector[{x, f[x]}, f'[x], .5], {x, Subdivide[-2, 2, 8]}]
```

> ```
> {{{-2., 0.}, {-1.87873, 0.485071}}, 
>  {{-1.5, 1.75}, {-1.34189, 2.22434}}, 
>  {{-1., 3.}, {-0.776393, 3.44721}}, 
>  {{-0.5, 3.75}, {-0.146447, 4.10355}}, 
>  {{0., 4.}, {0.5, 4.}}, 
>  {{0.5, 3.75}, {0.853553, 3.39645}}, 
>  {{1., 3.}, {1.22361, 2.55279}}, 
>  {{1.5,1.75}, {1.65811, 1.27566}}, 
>  {{2., 0.}, {2.12127, -0.485071}}}
> ```

Now I will plot the curve `4 - x^2` along with the tangent vectors.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dotted},
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .2}, {.5, Automatic}},
  Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Arrow /@ tangetVectors}]
```

[image: plot]

If you don't want to put the vectors on plot, but only want to show the vectors themselves, use `Graphics` in place of `Plot`

```
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1.75], Arrow /@ tangetVectors}]
```

[image: graphics]