# Plotting single vectors in parametric plots

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to plot something like the [Frenet-Serret Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) using a parametric plot, like this:

```
    r[t_] := {t, t^2, 2 t^3/3}
    t[t_] := r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]]
    Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, 0, p} 
      PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}], {p, 10^-10, 1}]
```

Now I would like to have the function `t[x]` also plotted, but as a single vector at the coordinates of the current point `r[p]`.

This probably helps to visualize what I am trying to do, as it is exactly the same thing: [Frenet-Serret Frame moving along a parametric helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Frenetframehelix.gif)

The helix would be my function `r` and `t` is the first of those three vectors that I would like to see moving around.

I tried two things, first using

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, 0, p} 
      PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}},
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{r[p], t[p]}]}], {p, 10^-10, 1}]
```

But the Arrow is shown as an overlay in 2D above the plot, and then

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, 0, p} 
      PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}},
 Epilog -> {ParametricPlot3D[t[p]*u, {u, 0, 1}] /. Line -> Arrow}], {p, 10^-10, 1}]
```

which I cannot get to work because `ParametricPlot3D` is not a primitive that can be shown in `Epilog`

So, any ideas? <s>I'm sure, because I'm just a noob.</s>

Thanks in advance guys and have a nice day :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/56469#56469

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) creates a 2D graphic that is overlayed on top of the main image.  From the **Details** section of the documentation

> In three-dimensional graphics, two-dimensional graphics primitives can be specified by the Epilog option.

Thus we have to create a seperate 3D object and "overlay"/superimpose it onto the parametric plot with [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).  And to make sure we can always see all or the arrows (i.e. make it so the arrows don't go outside of the bounding box), we need to find the right plot range.

## Finding the right plot range

**Summary**: We need to find the minimum of the minima and the maximum of the maxima of each coordinate of each vector over the parametric domain.

Given the curves

```
r[t_] := {t, t^2, 2 t^3/3}
v[t_] := Normalize[r'[t]] /. Abs[x_] :> x
```

the probably-not-best-way to find the right plot range is to find the minimum and maximum values of each coordinate of each vector over the whole time.

```
(
  {NMinValue[{#, 0 < t < 1}, t], NMaxValue[{#, 0 < t < 1}, t]} & /@ (
    r[t] + 0.5 Normalize@#
  )
) & /@ {v[t], v'[t], Cross[v[t], v'[t]]}
```

> ```
> {
>   (*Min and Max for each x,y,z for v[t]*)
>   {{0.5, 1.16667}, {0., 1.33333}, {1.42102*10^-19, 1.}}, 
>   (*v'[t]*)              {{7.95036*10^-15, 0.666667}, {0.414214, 0.833333}, {0., 1.}}, 
>   (*Cross[v[t], v'[t]]*) {{0., 1.33333}, {-0.164252, 0.666667}, {0.415978, 0.833333}}
> }
> ```

Then group them by coordinate

```
Transpose[%, {3, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {
>   {
>     (*Minimum x for v[t], v'[t], Cross[v[t], v'[t]]*) 
>     {0.5, 7.95036*10^-15, 0.}, 
>     (*y*) {0., 0.414214, -0.164252}, 
>     (*z*) {1.42102*10^-19, 0., 0.415978}
>   }, 
>   (*Maxima*) {
>     {1.16667, 0.666667, 1.33333},
>     {1.33333, 0.833333, 0.666667},
>     {1., 1., 0.833333}}
> }
> ```

Then find the minimal minimum and maximal maximum of each coordinate so that each vector is always within the formed box.

```
infimumbox = Transpose@{Min /@ %[[1]], Max /@ %[[2]]}
```

> ```
> {
>  (*Min, Max x for all vectors over time*) {0., 1.33333}, 
>  (*y*) {-0.164252, 1.33333}, 
>  (*z*) {0., 1.}
> }
> ```

And those edges form the smallest cuboid that holds all three vectors over the whole parametric domain.

## Making the animation

Now that we have a plot range `infimumbox`, we can animate the problem.

Since we need to plot from zero to something positive, we can't include `p = 0` in our time/parametric domain.  So instead we choose the closest thing, [`$MinMachineNumber`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MinMachineNumber.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[
   r[t],
   {t, 0, p}, 
   PlotRange -> infimumbox
  ],
  Graphics3D[
   {Thickness[.006],
    {Red, Arrow[{r[p], r[p] + 0.5 Normalize@t[p]}]},
    {Blue, Arrow[{r[p], r[p] + 0.5 Normalize[t'[p]]}]},
    {Darker[Green, 3/5], Arrow[{r[p], r[p] + 0.5 Normalize@Cross[t[p], t'[p]]}]}
   }
  ],
  PlotRange -> infimumbox
 ],
 {p, $MinMachineNumber, 1, Animator}
]
```

[image]

Another example (a simple helix i.e. `r[t_] := {Cos[2 π t], Sin[2 π t], 0.5 t}` which yields `infimumbox = {{-1.11733, 1.11733}, {-1.11733, 1.11733}, {0., 2.06922}}` over the domain of `$MinMachineNumber <= t <= π`) that clearly shows the relationship between the vectors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! Accepted! But two more questions: 1) Is there any way to specify an open interval so you dont have that nasty `0.001` in `{p, 0.001, 1, Animator}` ? And 2), whats the best way to keep them arrows from disappearing to the outside of the bounding box without making them smaller or the box bigger?

Comment: Wow thank you very much, this is way more than I could have hoped for! If I could upvote again I definitely would, this has helped me a lot to understand how the Mathematica Language and Phiilosophy works!

Answer (score 4):

Try `Show`:

```
Manipulate[Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, 0, p}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}],
  Graphics3D@Arrow[{r[p], t[p]}]
  ], {p, 10^-10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, would have accepted this as well, but @That Gravity Guy 's answer is slightly more detailed. Thanks in any case!

Comment: @JustAGuy You're welcome!