# How Can I draw a curve on a sphere in Minkowski 3 space?

Tags: differential-geometry

There is a curve, which evolves with time, in the the Euclidean space. And the solution of its evolution equations has been used to draw it using this code:

```
gm[u_] :=
 (eqns = {t'[s] == \kappa[s] n[s], 
    n'[s] == -\kappa[s] t[s] + \tau[s] b[s], 
    b'[s] == -\tau[s] n[s], r'[s] == t[s], t[0] == t0, n[0] == n0, 
    b[0] == b0, r[0] == r0}; 
 
  \alpha = .4; \beta = 0.5; 

  \kappa[s_] =2 \beta Sech[u \alpha + s \beta];
  \tau[s_] = 1 - \alpha/\beta;   
  
  {t0, n0, b0} = Orthogonalize[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
  r0 = {0, 0, 0};

  sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n, b}, {s, -10, 10}];
  Graphics3D[
   Text[Style["t=" <> ToString[u], Black, Italic, 
     30], {Evaluate[r[10] /. sol]}]])

Show[Table[f[u], {u, 0, 4}], Table[gm[u], {u, 0, 4}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

where, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, $\kappa$ is the curvature and $\tau$ is the torsion. Also, u is the time and s is the arc length parameter.
How Can I do the same in the Minkowski 3 space?
I know I will change the Frenet Frame but, How can I draw the sphere in the Minkowski space and plot the curve on it?.
I used this code:

```
gm[u_] :=
 (eqns = {t'[s] == \kappa[s] n[s], 
    n'[s] == -\kappa[s] t[s] + \tau[s] b[s], 
    b'[s] == -\tau[s] n[s], r'[s] == t[s], t[0] == t0, n[0] == n0, 
    b[0] == b0, r[0] == r0}; 
 
  \alpha = .4; \beta = 0.5; 

  \kappa[s_] =1 - \alpha/\beta;
  \tau[s_] = 2 \beta Sech[u \alpha + s \beta]Tanh[u \alpha + s \beta];   
  
  {t0, n0, b0} = Orthogonalize[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
  r0 = {0, 0, 0};

  sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n, b}, {s, -10, 10}];
  Graphics3D[
   Text[Style["t=" <> ToString[u], Black, Italic, 
     30], {Evaluate[r[10] /. sol]}]])

Show[Table[f[u], {u, 0, 4}], Table[gm[u], {u, 0, 4}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

but the curve seems not nice and I do not know what is wrong. And How can I draw it on a sphere in the Minkowski space?.

Comment: `FrenetSerretSystem` is a built in function, e.g. this is related [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/56469#56469)

Comment: What are you doing here: `$\kappa[s]$`, and here: `$\tau[s]$` for example? Why the `$` signs?

Comment: @flinty, this is just sign of equations $$. \kappa is the curvature of the curve and \tau is the torsion.

Comment: @Artes, Here the case is a little bit different. we study the evolution equations of the curve and then we find the solution numerically and take those solutions to plot the curve. The evolution equations  in terms of the curvature and the torsion. In the topic you mentioned, we have the curve and so we find its tangent, normal and binormal and then plot it after finding also their curvatures.