# Parametric equations and eq. of tangent plane

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I have written the following code to determine the equation of a plane tangent to a surface at a given point:

```
z[x_, y_] := Log[x y^2 - 2]
zx[x_, y_] := Evaluate@D[z[x, y], x]
zy[x_, y_] := Evaluate@D[z[x, y], y]
tanPlane[x_, y_, x0_, y0_] := 
 Expand[z[x0, y0] + zx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + zy[x0, y0] (y - y0)]
tanPlane[x, y, 3, 1]
```

It works well. But I'm now interested in writing code to find the equation of a tangent plane to a given parametric surface at a specific point.

So, for example, say $x = u + v, y = 3u^2, z = u-v$; at point (2,3,0).

How would I write code to calculate the eq. of the tangent plane to this surface? I've got this so far, which gives me the normal vector.

```
x[t] := u^2
y[t] := v^2
z[t] := u + 2 v
R[t] := {x[t], y[t], z[t]}
Cross[D[R[t], u], D[R[t], v]]
```

What I want to do is to auto-evaluate the given point, which will solve for the right $u$ and $v$ and then write and simplify the eq. of the plane.

Comment: Would this help? [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18598/27951)

Comment: Checking that out; good code for other problems certainly, but trying to see how I can use it here.

Answer (score 3):

The following code seems to work for me

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, xyzuv, tanPlane];
xyzuv[u_,v_] := {u + v, 3 u^2, u - v};
tanPlane[x0_,y0_,z0_] := Module[{u, v, u0, v0, xyz, t},
  {u0, v0} = {u, v} /. First @ 
    Solve[(xyz = xyzuv[u, v]) == {x0, y0, z0}, {u, v}];
  t = Cross[D[xyz, u], D[xyz, v]] /. {u -> u0, v -> v0};
  Dot[t, {x, y, z} - {x0, y0, z0}]];
```

For example, the expression

```
tanPlane @@ xyzuv[1, 3] == 0
```

returns

```
-6(-4 + x) + 2(-3 + y) - 6(2 + z) == 0
```

which is the equation of the
tangent plane at `(4, 3, 2)` which comes from
`u=1` and `v=3`. The simplified form of the equation is
`3x - y + 3z = 3`.

Note that in the code I explicitly use global variables
`x,y,z` for the equation of the tangent plane.

Comment: Hmmm..... I can't get that work. I'm using MMA 12.2. But @Somos, your code gives me an error.

Comment: I got it to work. I just need to clear the variables. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The tangent plane should be `3 x - y + 3 z - 3 == 0`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks for your helpful comment! I changed the variable bindings of my code which works as it should now.

Answer (score 2):

In the old days, I would do it the way Somos did in his answer. These days, I very much like using the built-in region functionality of *Mathematica*:

```
surf[u_, v_] := {u^2, v^2, u + 2 v}

pla = InfinitePlane[surf[u, v], Transpose[D[surf[u, v], {{u, v}}]]];

Simplify[RegionMember[pla /. Thread[{u, v} -> {1, 1}], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
   3 + x + 2 y == 2 z
```

Of course, for visualization purposes, `pla` is already usable as is:

```
sstyle = Directive[Specularity[White, 3], ColorData[97, 1], 
                   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.197, 0.252, 0.333]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.155, 0.213, 0.298],
                                 ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.155, 0.213, 0.298], 
                                 ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.155, 0.213, 0.298],
                                 ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -3/2, 3/2}, {v, -3/2, 3/2}], 
     Graphics3D[{{sstyle, pla /. Thread[{u, v} -> {1, 1}]}, 
                 {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], ColorData[97, 4]],
                  Point[surf[1, 1]]}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: surface and its tangent plane]

(This was supposed to be a comment that got too long.)

Answer (score 0):

```
r[u_, v_] := {u^2, v^2, u + 2 v};
tangentPlane2[u0_, 
  v0_] := ({x, y, z} - r[u, v]) . 
     Cross[D[r[u, v], u], D[r[u, v], v]] == 0 /. {u -> u0, v -> v0} //
   Simplify
tangentPlane2[1, 1]
```

> `3 + x + 2 y == 2 z`

```
r[u_, v_] := {u^2, v^2, u + 2 v};
tangentPlane1[u0_, v0_] := 
 Module[{u, v}, 
  Last@RegionMember[
     InfinitePlane[r[u, v], {D[r[u, v], u], D[r[u, v], v]}], {x, y, 
      z}] /. {u -> u0, v -> v0}]
tangentPlane1[1, 1] // Simplify
```

> `3 + x + 2 y == 2 z`